# How to cancel Google Fusion Table importing data?

Tags: google-drive, google-fusion-tables

I have a document created using Google Fusion Table and when I tried to import an 8 kb csv file (*File* → *Import More Rows*), the document freezes at "0% importing", as shown below:

[image]

I can no longer add / delete / edit data on that document. It's basically stuck; rebooting doesn't help, clearing cache doesn't help, switching computers/browsers doesn't help.

It has been like this for the past <del>20 hours</del> 22 months. How can I fix this error?

Is there anyway to cancel the import so that I can continue working on the document?